# How to inspect or view data stored using gcloud datastore locally?

Tags: java, gcloud, datastore

I have the following unit test

```
  public void testStoreGroceryList() {
    Grocery beer = new Grocery("Beer", 10);
    GroceryList groceryList = new GroceryList();
    groceryList.addGrocery(beer);

    Grocery bread = new Grocery("Bread", 1);
    groceryList.addGrocery(bread);

    assert(groceryList.getNumberOfGroceries() > 0);

    ofy().save().entity(groceryList).now();

    assert(groceryList.id != null);
  }
```

I am running the glcoud emulator while the test is executed and everything is OK, no failed test. But how can I access the local datastore? I have the emulator running on port 8484 but http://localhost:8484/_ah/admin gives me `Not Found`

If I run mvn appengine:run I see that the datastore is available to me, but how do I access it while running unit tests to see how the data I am storing looks like?

I have run `gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init` and got

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=grocery-monkey
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8484
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8484/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8484
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=grocery-monkey
```

But I still cannot access the _ah/admin

Comment: I believe that you may be looking for [Using the local Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore). This will allow you to view your local Datastore contents. Please, bear in mind that Google is migrating the local development environment to use the [Cloud Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator).

Comment: When I follow the guide and check http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin I see no_app_id

Comment: Sounds like you may need to [manually set the variables](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#manually_setting_the_variables) for your port number and project id. If this is does not solve your issue, please edit your question with more information, including screenshots and guides that you followed, to be able to help you further.

Comment: I tried setting them manually, but I still have the same problem

Comment: What logs do you see for this issue? You are specifying to connect on localhost:8484, but what port is your Dev App Server *really* connecting to from what you can see in the logs? What version of Java are you using? Which version of Cloud SDK? Have you tried running localhost on other ports?Are you following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#Running_the_development_web_server)? Are you using Local development server or are you using the Local Datastore as specified in the docs? Looking forward to your reply.